# Redirect all requests with http to https

Tags: php, http

I need to redirect all requests with http to https.
It is difficult to me to do with php headers. 
Is there any perfect way to do it?

Comment: Please elaborate and post what you tryed so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess to redirect users to a different URL.
Include a .htaccess file with the following rules in www folder to direct incoming traffic from HTTP to HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am using cPanel. can I create this file in my public_html folder?

Comment: Yes. you can. file name should be .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach - again done in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```